# smart, selective C++ build process (compiling/linking) in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working with a large **C++** project (100K lines), and every time I change a line(s) I need to re-build it. Due to its size, it takes quite a while and that's hitting my performance. So, my question is: if there is any way to speed up the build time in **Visual Studio** in order to selectively re-compile only those files which actually changed. And thus re-using all the other unchanged compiled  files (object files). And then, obviously linking.

I know I should be able to do so directly from the command line as **Visual Studio** is actually doing it "behind the scenes". Though the **"Property Pages"** display the **Command Lines** for **compile** and **link**, I think it would get quite troublesome as these commands is so long that I will probably make edit mistakes. Thanks in advance for sharing your experience on how to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: Normally only changed files are compiled again.

Comment: harandk, so when compiling VS checks whether the file object changed or not ?

Comment: Yes, that should be the default case. There are two buttons, one to recompile all and the other for compiling selective. Eventually, something is wrong in the project settings?

Comment: got it, a subtle difference which makes the difference !